# How to access the subclass's Instance variable using the Array of Object?

Tags: java, inheritance, arrayobject

I want to access the variable 's' using the array of objects 'arr'? Please refer the code snippet.

```
    public class Array_Chp3 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array_Chp3[] arr = new Array_Chp3[3];
        arr[0] = new str();  // when used this line instead of the below line , getting the error "s cannot be resolved or is not a field"
        //arr[0] = new Array_Chp3(); // when used this line instead of the above line, getting the error s cannot be resolved or is not a field
        str obj = new str(); 
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
        System.out.println(arr.length);
        System.out.println(arr[0].s); // How to access the variable 's'?

        }
    }
    class str extends Array_Chp3{
         public String s = "string123 @ str"; 
    }
```

Error Message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    s cannot be resolved or is not a field
at Array_Chp3.main(Array_Chp3.java:17)

Comment: you need a getter in class str, which will return s. then you can call it like `arr[].getS();`

Comment: You didn't show the code of your `str` class (which BTW should be named with capital initial, `Str`). Does it have a field `s` which is accessible from there ?

Comment: @SantiBailors yes, he did show the code of `str`. Read the question.

Comment: @JBNizet Right, I had missed it, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is an array of Array_Chp3. That means that you decided that elements of this array are instances of Array_Chp3. You don't really care what concrete type they have, as long as they are instances of Array_Chp3.

What you store in its first element is a `str` instance. That's fine, since a `str` *is a* Array_Chp3 (it extends Array_Chp3).

But since the type of the array is Array_Chp3[], the compiler can't guarentee that its element are all instances of `str`. All it can guarantee is that they're instances of Array_Chp3.

You know that it's a `str` though, so you can tell the compiler: trust me, I know it's in fact a `str`. That is called a cast:

```
System.out.println(((str) arr[0]).s);
```

But it shows a design problem. If you need the elements to be instances of `str`, then the array should be declared as an array of `str`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it is str you can cast it like this:

```
System.out.println(((str)arr[0]).s);
```

Comment: this shouldnt work. if you read the error message you will understand why

Comment: I'm almost sure this will work ;)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes, it will. And your advice about a getter is completely wrong.

Comment: thank you @JB Nizet